# Remove empty spaces around icon of svg and drwa it on pdf in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, .net

As per the following code i was getting HTML elements. With help of this code, i was trying to remove the empty spaces around the icon.

```
   public Image DownloadImage(string fromUrl)
    {
        HtmlToImage htmlToImageConverter = new HtmlToImage();

        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(fromUrl);
        XElement svg_Element = document.Root;
        var viewBoxValues = svg_Element.Attribute("viewBox").Value.ToString().Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

        var svgString = svg_Element.ToString();

        if (viewBoxValues[2] > viewBoxValues[3])
        {
            svgString = svgString.Insert(5, "style=\"height:100%\"");
        }
        else
        {
            svgString = svgString.Insert(5, "style=\"width:100%\"");
        }


        StringBuilder htmlString = new StringBuilder();
        htmlString.Append(@"<html> <body style=""margin:0px;background-color:#cccbbd;"">");
        htmlString.Append(svgString);
        htmlString.Append(@"<script>");
        htmlString.Append(@"var svg = document.getElementsByTagName(""svg"")[0];");
        htmlString.Append(@"var bbox = svg.getBBox();");
        htmlString.Append(@"var viewBox = [bbox.x, bbox.y, bbox.width, bbox.height].join("" "");");
        htmlString.Append(@"svg.setAttribute(""viewBox"", viewBox);");
        htmlString.Append(@"</script>");
        htmlString.Append(@"</body></html>");

        try
        {
            var data = htmlString.ToString();
            data.Remove(0, 1);
            data.Remove(htmlString.Length - 1, 1);
            return htmlToImageConverter.ConvertHtmlString(data);
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        return null;
    }
```

When I try those elements on HTML page, the icon propotion perfectly match with browser window.

Ex : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pG4FS.png)

But when I was try to bind the same elements on pdf, the propotion of the icon doesn't match with pdf. it was placed at center

Ex : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBFhK.png)

How can i solve this issue or Is it possible to do dynamically?

Comment: How do you create the PDF?

Comment: The good result give a square while bad result is a rectangle and not showing all the letters.  In this case the width is greater than the height but the bad results is using the height for the final results instead of the width.   Maybe the IF and ELSE are backwards.

Comment: @jdweng, How can i do, not to convert  as square?

Comment: See style height and width here : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_table_sizes.asp#:~:text=HTML%20tables%20can%20have%20different%20sizes%20for%20each,add%20the%20style%20attribute%20to%20the%20%3Ctable%3E%20element%3A